# Is there any better documentation for bulk-email-verifier?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, email-validation, email-verification, bulk-email

So, I'm trying out a new project right now (the project is to verify emails). And I'm using the bulk-email-verifier library on google colab. The problem is that the code is wonky and I can't find any official documentation to make the code less wonky beside the two main site - ([site 1](https://emailverification.whoisxmlapi.com/bulk-api/integrations/developer-libraries/python), [site 2](https://pypi.org/project/bulk-email-verifier/)

The first issue is the download. The script is suppose to read a csv, verify it, and then download the result back into my local device. But the download doesn't work most of the time (it just returns an empty csv). Basically, I have to run the first line multiple times for a chance that the second line can download the right thing.

```
#code to get request - taken from site
client.download(filename='emails.csv', request_id=request_id)
```

```
#download csv
from google.colab import files
files.download('emails.csv')
```

The second problem is the results itself. The results aren't constant. I have some fake email, some generated by email generator, and some real. The fake email are fine, but the real email is not constant. The real email consist of work and personal emails. And the results keeps on returning as either - true or smtp-failed. Is this because of the library itself, or did I write something wrong?

```
#[make free account here to get api key if u want](https://emailverification.whoisxmlapi.com/bulk-api/integrations/developer-libraries/python)
pip install bulk-email-verifier
from bulkemailverifier import *
client = Client('API Key')
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()
```

```
file = pd.read_csv('email_test.csv')
file.head(15)
```

```
file.info()
files = file['email'].tolist()
```

```
request_id = client.create_request(emails = files)

result = client.get_status(request_ids = [request_id])
print (result)

completed = client.get_records(request_id=request_id)
failed = client.get_records(request_id=request_id, return_failed=True)
```

```
result = client.get_requests()
print(result)
```

```
#code to get request - taken from site
client.download(filename='emails.csv', request_id=request_id)
```

```
#download csv
from google.colab import files
files.download('emails.csv')
```

Comment: When you say "verify email", do you mean you're trying to verify whether an email  address maps to a valid person or not?  Are you not aware that the ability to do that was eliminated decades ago, specifically because it aids spammers?  Almost every mail server responds with success during the SMTP session, and returns a bounce message later.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I understood very little what you posted. All I wanted to do is to verify that the email is legit and not a 'spam' or 'invalid' email. Checking for syntax is easily done given that I can simply use re, but I wanted to take it a step beyond that. I wanted to make sure that the domain holding the email is real and the email exists. But I'm not sure on how to do this given that I am only a college junior (turning senior). So I looked for api to do that for me.

Comment: As for your response, I think that I am simply trying to verify if the email is real and not fake (don't care if it's temp). I also understand that we have lost the ability to 'verify' email (cause of spammer), but there are services out there that does validate email (which was what inspired me to do this project). And I understood very little about the SMTP part. Does that have something to do with the inconsistent result?

Comment: You CANNOT know whether an email is real or fake.  There is no path to do that, for anti-spam reasons.  All they can do is guess.  Have you investigated that library at all, or are you just blindly trusting it?  It uses a commercial service to do its job.  That service takes time to do its investigations -- multiple seconds.  If you request a result before the service is ready, you'll get an empty result, and you have to retry.

Comment: And since this is a commercial service (emailverification.whoisxml.com), I suggest you ask them for support.  You only get 1,000 checks for free, then you have to open a paid account.

Comment: I see. I will do as you advice. Thank you!